# How to get phone number of incoming call in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to fetch phone number of  incoming caller in my app.
Please someone provide me solution of this problem in swift.

Comment: Don't ask about...
**Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You will never be able to get the phone number of the incoming call since this is users private data, Apple will not allow you to acces the data.Its strictly restricted by Apple

Comment: But when I don't want to upload my app on appstore then Can I do this. If yes then provide me specific code.

Comment: @AmitSingh This is a platform restriction, not a app store policy.

Comment: As mentioned by @Filburt, its nothing to do with app store

Answer (score 0):

Check out Core Telephony Framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html

There is CTCall method, But CTCall identifying the call will only tell you the cureent state of call i.e is call being accepted or rejected. The callID of CTCall will just give you an unique identifier for that call but not the number being called.

**NOTE** your app should be in foreground state, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: It can work in background state as well now. I have tested on iOS 12 beta. Also after iOS 10 there is a new framework called "CallKit" in replacement to "CoreTelephony".

Comment: That will be great